# C++ smart pointer auto free for dynamic array

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I want to auto free my dynamic array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>    

void myFunction(int* arg)
{
    // do something without delete
}

int main ()
{
  int* l_pBuffer = new int[8];

  std::unique_ptr<int[]> l_autoFree(l_pBuffer);  //<--- option 1
  std::unique_ptr<int> l_autoFree(l_pBuffer);    //<--- option 2

  myFunction(l_pBuffer);

  return 0;
}
```

Since it is an dynamic array, should I go for option 1?

Comment: May I suggest using `std::make_unique<std::array<int, 8>>()`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: If the object was created by `new T[]` you need to store it in a `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`. Otherwise it will be destroyed with `delete` which is not compatible with `new[]`. Technically you could provide a custom deleter to `std::unique_ptr<int>` but there is no good reason for doing that here.

Comment: May I suggest using `std::vector<int> buffer(8);`?

Comment: Hello, I am wonder,
Is option 1 wrong ?
I feel option 1 is correct, but want to know more details.

Comment: Option 1 will compile, but IMHO is not something you usually want in your code IMHO... If you call `delete[]` on `l_pBuffer` you will have a majestic double free (e.g. if `myFunction` deletes...)

Comment: I just need it to auto free during exit the scope.

Comment: @MatteoRagni `std::make_unique<int[] >(8)` would make more sense for the example given. An `array<int, N>` is different than an `int[N]`. Also, creating a `unique_ptr<array>` instead of a `unique_ptr<int[]>` would require an extra dereference when indexing elements, as there would not be an `operator[]` defined for `unique_ptr<array>`

Comment: Why not using a local `std::vector<int>` and passing a `std::vector::data` then?

Comment: @RemyLebeau for sure you are right. But as a personal preference I stick with `std` containers as much as possible. Regarding deferencing and function arguments: with a `std::array`, if you call with `myFunction(array.data())` I think you get the same performance (dropping the std container obviously, but if the signature forces you to do so...). Am I right?

Comment: yes, I want to maintain the signatures.

Comment: Option 2 is wrong for the same reason that `int* p = new int[10]; delete p;` is wrong. You really should use `std::vector` to manage a dynamically allocated array. Your function can still be called using the `std::vector::data()` method.

Comment: @alterigel, option 1 is delete[] p.
option 2 is delete p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` when using an array allocated with `new[]`. Otherwise, the array will not be freed correctly.

A better option is to use `std::make_unique<T[]>()` instead, or even a `std::vector`.